# One HDD will not automatically go to sleep by hdparm

Tags: debian, hard-disk, hdparm

I'm using hdparm to automatically turn off hard discs after 5 minutes. I use this config:

```
# cat /etc/hdparm.conf 
quiet
/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD10EADS-00L5B1_WD-WCAU46879161 {
    spindown_time = 60
    write_cache = off
}
/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD10EADS-00L5B1_WD-WCAU4D923086 {
    spindown_time = 60
    write_cache = off
}
/dev/disk/by-id/ata-Hitachi_HDT721010SLA360_STF604MR2A0PYP {
    spindown_time = 60
    write_cache = off
}
/dev/disk/by-id/ata-Hitachi_HDT721010SLA360_STF604MR2BDA3P {
    spindown_time = 60
    write_cache = off
}
```

The first one is the system drive which never goes to sleep, which is OK.

The two Hitachi drives are going to sleep as expected but the second WD drive never goes automatically to sleep:

```
# hddtemp /dev/sd[abcd]
/dev/sda: WDC WD10EADS-00L5B1: 37°C
/dev/sdb: WDC WD10EADS-00L5B1: 32°C
/dev/sdc: Hitachi HDT721010SLA360: drive is sleeping
/dev/sdd: Hitachi HDT721010SLA360: drive is sleeping
```

But I can manually force to go to sleep mode:

```
# hdparm -Y /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
 issuing sleep command
# hddtemp /dev/sd[abcd]
/dev/sda: WDC WD10EADS-00L5B1: 37°C
/dev/sdb: WDC WD10EADS-00L5B1: drive is sleeping
/dev/sdc: Hitachi HDT721010SLA360: drive is sleeping
/dev/sdd: Hitachi HDT721010SLA360: drive is sleeping
```

What's wrong with it? How to get automatic sleep working?

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a problem with WD Green HDDs. I've found an alternative for hdparm that works: [hd-idle](http://hd-idle.sourceforge.net/)

In /etc/default/hd-idle I set these parameters:

```
START_HD_IDLE=true
HD_IDLE_OPTS="-a /dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD10EADS-00L5B1_WD-WCAU4D923086 -i 180 -a /dev/disk/by-id/ata-Hitachi_HDT721010SLA360_STF604MR2A0PYP -i 180 -a /dev/disk/by-id/ata-Hitachi_HDT721010SLA360_STF604MR2BDA3P -i 180 -l /var/log/hd-idle.log"
```

And now all drives but the system drive are going to sleep correctly.